# Rails Contact Form with Refinery CMS - No Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, refinery

I have tried actionmailer and other gem methods to create a simple contact form in refinery. All I want this form to do is send an email. I have tried this at the app level, and I have tried to add these within the vendor folders as a separate extension.. I can't seem to create a simple form without creating a refinery:engine and it being saved to the database. Does anyone have a simple method for this?